# Browser's geolocation displaying two initial locations

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-phones

I wrote a map page that uses geolocation to detect the user's location. When the user clicks a button, this javascript is called:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
wpid = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
       setUserPosition(position, "Your location", pollUserPosition);
       }, 
       function() { handleNoGeolocation(true); },
       { enableHighAccuracy: false, maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 10000 }
    );
}
```

From what I understand, watchPosition will start polling the user's location until it's told to stop. This is done by calling clearWatch and passing in the wpid from the watchPositon call. setUserPosition will create a marker on the map based upon the location in position. When I test this page in mobile safari sometimes I get two initial locations marked on the map. Does anyone know why I'd get two locations returned and how I can only return one? Is it because a location is returned using both the cell connection and the wifi connection on the iPhone?

**Update:**
As a test, I turned off WiFi on the phone and tested the map page again. Unfortunately, I'm still getting two initial locations when I call watchPosition.

Answer (score 0):

with watchPosition, you will get updated position information on the callback if the position data changes either by device movement or if more accurate geo information arrives.

So if you want only ONE position try using the:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

This should only return ONE position. Have you tried that already?

Comment: I know that getCurrentPosition will only get the user's location once, but for my project I need to continually update the user's location. The issue I'm having is that when I start calling watchPostion, it appears that the first successful call back returns 2 locations.

Comment: Can you output these positions (console.log) for us? So you're saying it's returning an Array of positions[]? Sure it's not 2 successful callbacks?

Comment: I ran a test and I have some new theories as to what is happening. I noticed that sometimes, watchPosition will return two values within several milliseconds of each other. In a few tests I found that the timestamps of the results were within 500 ms of each other. I think what is happening is that since these calls are so close together, there are two requests made to google maps and they are both being rendered in the same response. Right now this is my theory. I'm going to add some code to check if the map is still being rendered before making another call.